# SSRS Chart: Add a Baseline

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I try to put in SSRS in a chart bar a target line and a baseline. I add in my chart with stripline a target line. But I would like to show it like this:
[image]

The chart1 is the chart which I would create in SSRS. And the chart2 is the chart which I create in SSRS. How can I add only one bar at the beginning of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there is a parameter or equivalent identifying where the Baseline should be (even if it is the current date)

If so, you can have the baseline series to only display a value for the column you want to set as the baseline.

In this example I have a number of students, and want to display a baseline column where the student name is `Student1`

Add a new series to the chart, and set the expression to be

```
=iif(Fields!Student.Value = "Student1", Sum(Fields!Val.Value), 0)
```

This will mean that it will only return a value when the column is for `Student1`, otherwise it will return zero.

Conversely, you could set the other columns to be values *except* for when they are Student1 as follows

```
=iif(Fields!Student.Value <> "Student1", Sum(Fields!Val.Value), 0)
```

Using a Stacked Column chart for these series would give this output

[image]

Alternatively, you could use dates for the X axis, and use a parameter to set the date for the baseline, and use a expression such as this to identify the baseline column

```
=iif(Fields!myXAxisDate.Value = Parameters!myBaselineDate.Value, Sum(Fields!mYValue.Value), 0)
```

Hopefully this will assist you.  Please let me know if you have further questions on this.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. I used the first expression.

Comment: One question to targetline. How can I show the targetline like in the picture(chart1)

Comment: I assume targetline is another series of values in the chart?  Just change the chart type for this series to Line Chart.